# Wix Installer: is there a way to have overlapping controls?

Tags: wix, installation

I've got an installer set up and I'm trying to get text box controls to appear within a radio button. See below:

[image: Installer with radio buttons and text controls]

The problem I've got is while it looks correct, because the text boxes are on top of the radio button, I can't click where they overlap.

I've tried reversing the file position of each element, but that resulted in not being able to see the text boxes. I also considered splitting up the radio button, but I don't seem to be able to do that.

```
<Control Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="USERCERTIFICATE" Id="USERCERTIFICATE" X="20" Y="80" Width="240" Height="160">
      <RadioButtonGroup Property="USERCERTIFICATE">
        <RadioButton Text="Generate an untrusted self-signed certificate" Value="0" X="0" Y="0" Width="220" Height="13" />
        <RadioButton Text="Supply an existing certificate file (.pfx)" Value="1" X="0" Y="20" Width="280" Height="13" />
        <RadioButton Text="Configure later" Value="2" X="0" Y="130" Width="220" Height="13" />
      </RadioButtonGroup>
    </Control>

    <Control Id="CertificatePathLabel" Type="Text" X="40" Y="120" Width="240" Height="15" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Select the certificate location:">
        <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[USERCERTIFICATE <> "1"]]></Condition>
        <Condition Action="enable">USERCERTIFICATE = "1"</Condition>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="CertificatePath" Type="Edit" X="40" Y="135" Width="240" Height="18" Property="CERTIFICATEPATH">
        <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[USERCERTIFICATE <> "1"]]></Condition>
        <Condition Action="enable">USERCERTIFICATE = "1"</Condition>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="ChangeCertificatePath" Type="PushButton" X="280" Y="135" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgChange)">
        <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[USERCERTIFICATE <> "1"]]></Condition>
        <Condition Action="enable">USERCERTIFICATE = "1"</Condition>
    </Control>

    <Control Id="CertificatePasswordLabel" Type="Text" X="40" Y="162" Width="240" Height="15" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Enter the password to use for the certificate:">
        <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[USERCERTIFICATE <> "1"]]></Condition>
        <Condition Action="enable">USERCERTIFICATE = "1"</Condition>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="CertificatePassword" Type="Edit" X="40" Y="177" Width="240" Height="20" Property="CERTIFICATEPASSWORD" Password="yes">
        <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[USERCERTIFICATE <> "1"]]></Condition>
        <Condition Action="enable">USERCERTIFICATE = "1"</Condition>
    </Control>
```

Any pointers would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to remove the labels from the radio button control and resize to be only 13px wide. I then added test boxes to replace the labels. It's a bit hacky, and I've lost the functionality to click on the text to make a selection, but it works.

I'd still appreciate if anyone has a better solution.